# AppStore won't install OS X 10.10.5 update

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I am trying to install the 10.10.5 update. It seems impossible. Every time I click "update" in the AppStore and confirm the reboot, a dialog pops up: The available updates have changed. When I click "Show details", nothing happens and the update gets added to the installed updates.

Maybe the download is broken? How can I force the AppStore to re-download the patch? Can I install the update anyway? Where does the AppStore put its downloads?

[image: AppStore says the available updates have changed]

[image: Lots of "installed" 10.10.5 updates]

Comment: Installing manually works as expected.

Comment: I just had this happen during a Sierra update. Killing iTunes allowed me to continue the update via the UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I updated from 10.10.4 and had the very same problem. Even after rebooting this loop did not end. I solved it by installing the update from the command line with this command:

`softwareupdate -i -a`

In order to issue this command, open the Terminal application and enter the command. The tool downloaded the software update package and installed it. At the end the tool notifies you to restart your system. After the restart 10.10.5 was installed and everything was fine.

For details about this tool see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200113

Comment: If you get `Error installing updates.` when running that command, first run `sudo -s`.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the AppStore to install the update, but I downloaded [the combo update from Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832?locale=de_DE). It's much larger (2GB instead of 800MB), but can be installed without the AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

The Combo update is needed if you did not update to 10.10.4.  If you are running 10.10.4 you need only the (non-combo) update which is 1 gb rather than 2.